# Nested sum solution | SQL | Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested, sum

I am looking for a nested sum solution. I guess, I need to somehow filter by “Shareholder” and herein sum the matches between “Subs. – Date of incorporation” and “Year”. Your support is highly appreciated!

I would like to transform this table,

[image: Excel table]

into the following outcome table:

[image: Wished result format]

I tried it with the following, however, the counter is not correct, resp. not changing accurately. For ABC it would show “2” subsidiaries for 2013, 2014 and 2015.

**SELECT** YEAR([Table1].[Year]), [Table1].[Shareholder], COUNT([Table1].[Shareholder]) AS [No of Subs]
**FROM** Table1
**WHERE** YEAR([Table1].[Year]) <= [Table1].[ Subs. – Date of incorporation]
**GROUP BY** [Table1].[Shareholder],  [Table1].[Year];

I am an absolute beginner to SQL and would be happy about any help. Many thanks!

Comment: Please let people know your approach first.

Comment: Please see the edited version. That's the best I can do. Absolute SQL beginner. Thanks.

Comment: What you're trying to do is eliminate rows that relate to years before the year of incorporation, so: `WHERE YEAR(Table1.Year) >= YEAR(Table1.[Subs. – Date of incorporation])`. That removes lines 1, 2, and 4 in your table. The only problem is that if you need the years to stay in even when there are no subsidiaries, then remove the `WHERE` clause entirely and use this in the select instead of the count `SUM(IIF(YEAR(Table1.Year) >= YEAR(Table1.[Subs. – Date of incorporation]), 1, 0)) AS [No of Subs]`

Comment: @Steve: Many thanks! It's working great - you made my day!